# Sending SSL info to target endpoint in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using https target end point and the target is expecting the keystore information. We have updated the WSO2 server jks file to include the certificate that the target end point is expecting. Looking at the carbon.log (in DEBUG), I don't see any SSL related information. Where do/how do I see this information logged?

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  Did you update the wso2carbon.jks or the client-truststore.jks?  Are you seeing any error, or some type of result from an attempted transaction?  Have you tried turning up the logging on org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire using the logging configureation console?

Comment: Thank you! We updated client-truststore.jks, but getting the 403 forbidden error from the target end point. We want to understand what information (from SSL perspective) is passed to the target. We have the wire logging enabled, but did not find any information in the logs. Wanted to understand if there is any other cofiguration that we need to change/update.